# How to change this C code to prefetch some data?

Tags: c, loops, matrix, openmp, prefetch

I make an application which checks matrix  efficiency. I use various methods (for example change loops, 2/3 loops, openmp etc). One thing left: I have to check data prefetch.

Code:

```
#define SIZE 5000

for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
 for(int j=0;j<SIZE;j++)
   mul+=tab[i][j]
```

Usually processor `prefetch` data by itself (when we are in single row and increment `j`), but not always (for example `tab[0][0]` is never `prefeched` or when we go to next row (`loop i++ ,tab[i][0]`)). How to change this code to help `proc` `prefetch` data from `tab[0][0], tab[1][0],tab[2][0],tab[3][0]`, etc before we will count them?

Comment: Which compiler/platform are you using?

Comment: I use visual studio with openMP

Answer (score 1):

You can use the prefetch builtin functions:

void _m_prefetch(void *);

You want to prefetch AT LEAST 128 bytes ahead of where you are. You will probably need to unroll your loop so that it does the right amount of work between each prefetch, or you'll waste clock-cycles on the actual prefetch instruction.

I suspect, however, that the processor will do a decent job of prefetching by itself, as you are reading memory "straight ahead" [assuming tab is a two-dimensional compile-time array, rather than a run-time built array].